# subl --wait doesn't work within tmux

Tags: sublimetext2, tmux

Setting and using Sublime Text 2 as the git editor does not wait correctly within a tmux session.

```
$ tmux
$ export EDITOR="subl -w" 
$ git rebase HEAD^ -i (close file, terminal hangs)
```

If the `EDITOR` is set without the wait, then the file is opened in ST2 as before, but then of course the rebase then gets applied immediately within the shell.

Comment: Just wanted to note that I am experiencing the same problem with tmux and sublime.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I do not use *Sublime Text*, but I have read [a question on Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/522055/subl-w-doesnt-ever-un-block-when-running-under-tmux-on-os-x) that seems to be about this same problem.

The solution involves using the [“wrapper” program](https://github.com/ChrisJohnsen/tmux-MacOSX-pasteboard) that I made to allow pasteboard access inside *tmux*. The “fix” is not specific to pasteboard access, so the program also turns out to alleviate problems in several other areas that are not related to cut/copy/paste operations. The method that *Sublime Text* uses to implement the “wait” feature of `subl -w` invocations seems to be one of these “other areas”.

You can get the wrapper through MacPorts from their [**tmux-pasteboard** port](https://trac.macports.org/browser/trunk/dports/sysutils/tmux-pasteboard/Portfile), or through Homebrew from their [**reattach-to-user-namespace** formula](https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/blob/master/Library/Formula/reattach-to-user-namespace.rb), or compile it yourself from my [**tmux-MacOSX-pasteboard** repository](https://github.com/ChrisJohnsen/tmux-MacOSX-pasteboard) at GitHub.

Once you have it installed, you may want to configure (per the README) a `default-command` in your `.tmux.conf` so that shells spawned inside *tmux* will automatically be “reattached”. Alternatively, you could use the wrapper in your EDITOR value:

```
EDITOR='reattach-to-user-namespace subl -w'
```

Comment: The .tmux.conf change didn't work for me, but explicitly adding it to the EDITOR did — thanks!